# Digital root of a number using recursion

Tags: python, numbers, digits

I am writing a recursive function to calculate the digital root of a given number:

```
def digital_root(num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        sum += num % 10
        num = num // 10

    while sum > 10:
        sum = digital_root(sum)

    return sum
```

I am not sure if the second `while` should be replaced with an `if` statement, and if so, why? (and if not, why not?)

When I try both of the version, the return value is the same.
For example, for the number `10598`, the output in both of them is `5`.

Comment: give an example input and output.

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy I added example and more explanationץ

Comment: ... is my answer right or wrong?

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy It's working, but that's not what I asked about.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to accept the answer if it works tired of people not accepting my solutions, when it works for them

```py
def digital_root(num):
    #Base case for recursion.
    # recursion always needs a base case
    if len(str(num)) == 1:
        return num
    #Get sum of num by turning it into a string and looping through it, 
    #adding each index one by one
    sum = 0
    for i in str(num):
        sum += int(i)
    #get the digital root of the sum
    return digital_root(sum)


def main():
    print(digital_root(27518))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There you go

Answer (score 0):

So, first, please think what you're asking.

If relates to a condition, and while relates to perform a repeated action as long as a certain condition holds.

The digital root recursion stops only when the resulting digit sum is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

we need "if" for the base case of recursion.
but in this special case, you are using "while" as "if" and that works. but for readability, it is better to use "if".

**the reason that it works:**

both "while" and "if" have conditions
and the difference between them is just looping through the instructions

and it will be the same again because of the recursion.

I mean in this special case, due to that we have recursion, "if" acts like "while"

Answer (score 0):

this is another answer for acounting the Digital root of a number using recursion:

```py
def digital_root(n):
    if(n < 10):
        return n
    n=n%10+digital_root(n//10)
    return digital_root(n)
```

Comment: Usually a code block with no explanation is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!